# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32timezone' on windows service python .exe file

Tags: python, windows-services, pyinstaller, pywin32

This code performs a fault simulation:

## my_service.py

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager

class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'MyService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'My Service'

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                            (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # Your service logic goes here
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)
```

I export it as exe file using pyinstaller, And when I try to install it on Windows Server OS  I got this error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32timezone'**